# Position div below a div with position absolute

Tags: html, css

I have one container on my website, which is 1024px wide. I place my divs one below another inside. But I wanted one of them to fill the screen width, so I had to use `position: absolute` on it. The problem is that when I place the next div below it, it goes in place of the absolutely positioned div. Something like:

```
<div style="width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto;">
   <div style="position: absolute; height: 500px;">
   </div>
   <div style="height: 100px;">
      It's at the top of the upper div.
   </div>
</div>
```

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try position:relative instead of absolute and set width to 100%

Answer (score 0):

By default, a `div` should "fill the screen width" as it's display is block and the default width is 100% (when using the default positioning of a div [which is static]).

Nevertheless, if you want the "lower" div to start just after the "upper" div (and you want to continue to use absolute positioning on the upper div) you can make it's position absolute as well, and set the `top` attribute to the height of the upper div.

```
<div style="width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto;">
   <div style="position: absolute; height: 500px; top:0; left:0;">
   </div>
   <div style="height: 100px; position:absolute; top:500px; left:0;">
      It's at the top of the upper div.
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the height was dynamic?

Comment: Then don't use absolute positioning. By using static or relative positioning, the other divs will position themselves immediately below the previous div

Comment: Then how can I create 100% screen div inside 1024px container without absolute positioning?

Comment: by default a div is 100% width of its parent element. in your case the div will be 1024px. if you want the div to be 100% of the body, then move the div outside of the "1024px div".

Answer (score 0):

Your `CSS` needs to be something like this:

```
section {
display: block;
width: 1024px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

section div:nth-of-type(1) {
height: 500px;
}

section div:nth-of-type(2) {
height: 100px;
}
```

And your `HTML` something like this:

```
<section>
<div>
</div>

<div>
Now it's where it should be.
</div>
</section>
```